Error after adding react-native config: Cannot use import statement outside a module
While developing a React-native app I was using process.env to check whether my app was in production or development in my app.config.ts :
import { ExpoConfig, ConfigContext } from 'expo/config';    
import Config from "react-native-config"
const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"

console.log("CONFIG", Config.NODE_ENV)

export default ({ config }: ConfigContext): ExpoConfig => ({
   ...config,
   extra: {
      endpoint: isProd ? "AA" : "BB"
   }
   ...

but i noticed that the process.env its not set when building from Xcode so i tried to add react-native-config in order to use the right .env each time.
After installing it with yarn add, adding pod 'react-native-config', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-config' and pod 'react-native-config/Extension', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-config' to podfile and trying to build the app i keep getting the following error:
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

@edit
I noticed i get the error only when trying to access the Config from app.config.ts during build time, whenever I access it at runtime it works. Now my question is, how should i configure it to make it work also while building, or should i approach it differently?


The error is related to the ES6 module syntax
(import/export) statement in the file where you're trying to
import NativeModules from 'react-native'.

Configure your project to use the ES6 module syntax throughout. It includes configuring babel to transpile your code and enabling the
esModuleInterop option in your babel.config.js file.

Alternatively, you can convert the file with the import statement to use CommonJS syntax (require/module.exports)
# Change this :
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';

# To this :
const { NativeModules } = require('react-native');



